# How do you specify that an sqlite datadase is contained withing the project

Tags: wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a connection string and want to know how to make it connect to a sqlite data base contained with a folder called Data within  my project.

The current connection string is as follows:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("DataSource=C:\\UbTv\\UbTvLite.db");
```

Tried different ways but can't get it to work.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("DataSource=..Data\UbTvLite.db");